# SQL Server 2012 Developer edition questions

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'd like to use SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition on our development/test server, which is a dedicated server rented from an online company.

When the product is ready, I would like to have it deployed on production server(s) using SQL Server 2012 Web Edition, by hosting with companies that offer SQL Server Web Edition through their SPLA.

1. Is this possible and the correct use of the Developer and Web editions?
2. Does Web Edition allow one to create multiple databases on the same physical server, and if so, how many?
3. How can I buy a license online for the developer edition? All online sales seem to be for physical media, and I don't have physical access to the development server, so the only option seems to be, to rip the CD/DVD and then upload it to the development server which would be a tedious process. I would like to download SQL Server directly on the development server, buy the development edition license online, and then put that license into SQL so it is properly licensed.

Thanks.

Comment: You might check with the company that host your development server, might have media available to install. Just show proof of license.

Comment: Well said. Would not be that unrealistic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: yes

2: yes. Limits generally are documented in the documentation. In this particular case you shall look to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx for all capacity specifcations for all editions of sql server.

3: Why you have to? Normally developers have MSDN (Microsoft Developers NEtwok) and get the licenses there.

Then - ever heard of google? Finsind a shop is trivial.

For example google and "sql server developer edition price" led me to
[http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Server-Developer-Edition-2012/dp/B007RFXQAM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007RFXQAM)

> so the only option seems to be, to rip the CD/DVD and then upload it to the 
>   development server which would be a tedious process.

No need to "rip" - a file copy is good enough. SQL Server does nothing fancy with the install media. But generally I keep ISO files around for all the stuff I need to develop - easier than looking for the DVD anyway every time I need to install it.

Generally if you want to do anything professional - or even semi professional - these days better stop assuming copying an ISO file up to the cloud is tendious. You will move a lot more around than you ever think of. This is 2013.

If you would have MSDN you could just download the ISO from the MS official repositories.

Comment: Thanks for answering 1 and 2. As for the third, I google-searched several things like your query and all the ones I checked were for boxed media. So I didn't think it was unreasonable to ask if purely the license could be bought. Because these database bundles are hundreds of GB in size and uploading something of that size takes hours, whereas downloading onto a server takes minutes. I have accepted your answer (but can't upvote it yet as I am new to dba.stackexchange). Thanks again!

Comment: Oh man,  I am pretty sure that the database bundles - which are delivered on a DVD btw., are NOT "hundreds of GB in size". Quite sure. I recently uploaded some ISO's to install a new server for a customer. Not even 5gb.

Comment: My bad, I most definitely was confusing hundreds of MB with hundreds of GB. Sorry, it's been a while since I downloaded SQL server! So my question 3 was really moot.